# Spring - link to parent lost when posting JSON object

Tags: java, json, spring

In my Angular + Spring application I have an entity `Logging` which has a parent `Project`:

```
@Entity
public class Logging implements Identifiable<Integer> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String message;
    private Date date;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Project project;
```

This is the endpoint I use to save a logging:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logging", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Logging saveLogging(@RequestBody Logging logging) {
    return apiLoggingService.save(logging);
}
```

The JSON object I post now looks like this:

```
{
    id: null
    date: "2015-12-27T22:04:20.556Z"
    message: "test"
    project: {
        id: 16616,
       // ...
    }
}
```

But I also tried this:

```
{
    id: null
    date: "2015-12-27T22:04:20.556Z"
    message: "test"
    project: 16616,
}
```

How can I make sure that the foreign key to `project` is filled in when the object is saved to database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding this to my entities:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
```

I also removed the `JsonIgnore` I added before because of circular references.